# How to use .ejs variable inside js in Node script?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have an app.js file

```
  async function asyncCall() {
var consulta = await db_conn.conexion(CONSTANT.CONF_GENERA_REPORTE);
response.render('pages/report.ejs', { results: consulta.rows });
}
asyncCall();
```

and I'm painting a table in a report.ejs file

```
         ... <tbody>
            <% results.forEach(function(r) { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%=r .store%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%=r .create_date.toISOString().slice(0,10) %>
                </td>...
```

but i want to use the variable "results" inside the same .ejs file in a script that exports it to excel

```
<script>
    var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

    wb.SheetNames.push("Test Sheet");
    var ws_data = <% results %>; //............here
    var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);
    wb.Sheets["Test Sheet"] = ws;
 .....
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ejs in javascript. For example:

```
console.log("<%= user.id%>")
```

You should be careful when you want to set ejs in javascript statment must be in `" "`.